# How can a lambda function that consumes a SQS queue send the message to a Dead Letter Queue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an AWS lambda function that consumes data from an AWS SQS queue. If this lambda finds a problem when processing the data of a message, then this message has to be added in a dead letter queue.

The documentation I found is not clear about how can I make the lambda send the message to the Dead Letter Queue. How is that accomplished?

Should I use the sendMessage() method, like I'd do to insert in a standard queue, or is there a better approach?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, *you* cannot send a message to a DLQ. SQS does this, based on a policy that you define for problematic messages. if you want a manual DLQ then you could simply create a new queue purely for that purpose.

Comment: @jarmod - you can indeed send a message to it - see my answer below

Comment: @Krease thanks for the correction. I’ll have to go try this out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AWS will automatically send messages to your [dead-letter-queue (DLQ)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html) for you if `receiveMessage` returns that message too many times (configurable on the queue with `maxReceiveCount` property) - typically this happens if you receive a message, but don't delete it (if for example, you had some exception in processing it). This is the simplest way to use a DLQ - by letting AWS put messages there for you.

However, **there's nothing wrong with manually sending a message to a DLQ**. There's nothing special about it - it's just another queue - you can send and receive messages from it, or even give it its own DLQ!

Manually sending messages to a DLQ is useful in several scenarios, the simplest one being your case: when you know the message is broken (and want to save time trying to reprocess it).  Another example is if you need to quickly burn through old items in your main queue but still save those messages for processing later - enabling you to catch up from backlog by processing more recent events first.

The key things to remember when manually sending a message to a DLQ are:

1. Send the message to the queue FIRST
2. Mark the message as consumed in the original queue (using `deleteMessage`) so AWS's automatic mechanisms don't put it there for you later.

   - if you delete the message from the original queue first, there is a small chance the message is lost (ie: if you crash or have an error before storing the message elsewhere)

Comment: Thank you, I believe your answer will be totally complete if you mention the "maxReceiveCount" attribute in the parenthesis.

Comment: @AriJnr - Updated - also clarified that order of operations within transferring the message is important in order to not lose messages (send to DLQ first, then delete from original queue)

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to send messages to the dead letter queue, messages that fail to process too many times will get there on their own see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html#sqs-dead-letter-queues-how-they-work)

The point is you get the message, fail on it, don't delete it, and after `maxReceiveCount` times it will redrive it to the DLQ.

Note that you can simply send it to the DLQ (Hinted on by the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html#sqs-dead-letter-queues-troubleshooting) see where it says `The NumberOfMessagesSent and NumberOfMessagesReceived for a Dead-Letter Queue Don't Match`) however it seems like an abuse, to me at least.

TLDR: You're not supposed to send it yourself, the queue needs to be configured with a DLQ and Amazon will do it for you after a set amount of failures.

Comment: While AWS does send messages to a DLQ on your behalf when you exceed `maxReceiveCount`, the focus of your answer is incorrect - **there's nothing wrong with sending messages to a DLQ yourself.**

Comment: I believe the original intent of the question was for the nature of the DLQ and how messages get there, I was trying to explain common usage pattern of DLQ. Usually (and in most serverless documentation) folks don't send messages there.

Comment: Thank you guys. user1730969, you are right about the intention of the question, but Krease gave me the answer I needed: I can either allow receivement of this message with receiveMessage() a certain amount of times (maxReceiveCount), or remove the message from the main queue and then send the broken message directly to the DLQ.

Comment: @AriJnr - make sure the ordering is correct to avoid potential dropped messages - add it to the DLQ first, THEN remove it from the main queue.

Comment: this largely depends on the use case. imagine you receive 1k messages a second, and you start receiving non-parsable json (or any non-retryable error). on top of that, you have 5 retries, and on top of that, you have 5 minutes visibility timeout (please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71449349/making-sqs-message-visible-again-using-partial-batch-response). processing can quickly clog and invisible message count increase, which also has limits. so while standard SQS retry/DLQ mechanism does sound good on paper, on practice it might be far from enough.